# jQuery dynamic script tag addition causes IE9 to request src twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Just came across something really weird with IE9 (how unusual?)

I have the following code to overcome cross domain restrictions and load a javascript that runs on localhost

```
 var url = 'http://local.maglnk.com:45099/download/?info_hash='+info_hash;
 var scriptTag = $('<script />').attr('src',url);
 scriptTag.appendTo('body');
```

This code works fine on any browser other than IE9, the weird thing with it is that IE9 requests the url of the script tag twice, and the second time that it does it it appends some sort of timestamp at the end of the URL

```
 http://local.maglnk.com:45099/download/?info_hash=6eabb12b8bf344feba7d323c940c18d096771b99&_=1309998922080)
```

I'm not sure if the trailing "&_=1309998922080" is added by jQuery when it appends the script tag dynamically, or if IE is doing some sort of pre-fecthing or pre-parsing in which case I come to ask here if there's a way to stop that mechanism via javascript.

If you've ever come across something like this please drop a line.

Comment: have you tried with `$('<script type="text/javascript" />')` just in case it chokes ...

Comment: What I have noticed when appending script tags with jQuery in IE9 is that the initial request appears to always get a 304 response from the server. It looks like when jQuery gets a 304 in IE, it immediately sends a 2nd request with a timestamp as a URL variable to prevent any chance of caching of the script.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery anyhow, why not use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Do not use the appendTo() jQuery method. Instead use $.getScript(url) and the issue goes away.

So, it seems like it's a jQuery issue with IE9 when you dynamically add script tags.

Cheers.

Comment: ahh.. cool +1. Nice catch, and you can ignore my comment in the question :)

Comment: I think it's more accurately an old IE issue JQuery tries to deal with in a goofy way which ends up duplicating the same issue in all browsers. There was something about an older version of IE firing scripts twice when appended. When I'm calling the shots, I avoid executable code dropped in via appended Script tags altogether. It's more ideal in my experience to have your JS deal with changing HTML than HTML changing your JS.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases `$.getScript()` might not be suitable, because it can mess up the order of the loaded javascript files. That's because it is asynchronous. If the dynamically loaded JavaScript files are dependencies of each other, that would cause issues.

In that case, you'll want to do this:

`$( document.body ).append( $( '<script src="hello.js"></script>' ) );`